# Writing a bash script from another script in literal mode

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

In a `bash` script I'm creating another `bash` script to launch a program:

```
$optionsfile="options.conf"     

tee "launch-script.sh" > /dev/null <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
bash $binFile `cat $optionsfile` &
EOF
```

I want the output script `launch-script.sh` to be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash $binFile `cat options.conf` &
```

So I would like to have the script to expand the `$optionsfile` but not to execute the `cat` command.
Now I'm getting:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash $binFile -ops1 -ops2 -ops3 &
```

Is it possible to achieve this? I'm doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**

Using the answers and the comment so far I found that the better solution would be using escaping:

```
$optionsfile="options.conf"     

tee "launch-script.sh" > /dev/null <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
bash $binFile \$(< $optionsfile) &
EOF
```

Comment: Better remove the leading whitespace from the heredoc: `#!` must be the first 2 characters of the file if you're depending on using the shebang functionality.

Comment: Note that the bash-specific `$(< options.conf)` is the same as `$(cat options.conf)`, except that it's builtin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backslashes to prevent interpolation:

```
tee "launch-script.sh" > /dev/null <<EOF
  #!/bin/bash
  bash \$binFile \`cat $optionsfile\` &
EOF
```

Comment: You beat me by 16 seconds... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Does normal escaping work?

```
tee "launch-script.sh" > /dev/null <<EOF
  #!/bin/bash
  bash \$binFile \`cat $optionsfile\` &
EOF
```